# Plot pandas columns with secondary y -axis and saving charts to a single pdf

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create multiple time-series plots using data in a Pandas DataFrame columns. I want to save all these charts to a single pdf file. The challenge is that these charts all have a secondary y-axis which has a different scale (see Col Z below). I have seen examples of saving multiple charts to pdf, and examples of plotting a singe chart with a secondary y-axis, but don't know how to combine the two. My actual DataFrame has 50 columns, so doing it manually would be tedious. Thanks in advance.

Here is what I tried:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4))
df1.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'Z']
date_range = pd.date_range('1/31/2011', periods=10, freq='M')
df1['Z'] = 100*df1['Z']
df1.plot(kind='line', subplots=True, secondary_y=['Z'])
#

import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf
pdf = matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages("output.pdf")
plt.figure()
for cols in df1.columns:
    df1.plot(y=cols, secondary_y=['Z'])
    pdf.savefig(fig)
pdf.close()
```

Comment: Where exactly is the difference between saving a figure with  and without a secondary axis? What problem do you encounter with your approach?

Comment: I need a secondary y-axis because the two series being plotted, say A and Z, have different scales. I am able to do that for one plot. However, I need to plot 50 such graphs (my real df has 50 columns). I am having trouble putting the plot() in a loop and saving the individual charts to the same pdf file for printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, I think this is what you are trying. This generate 4 graphs with 2 series in each one. Series `A`,`B`,`C` are plotted together with serie `Z`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4))
df1.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'Z']
date_range = pd.date_range('1/31/2011', periods=10, freq='M')
df1['Z'] = 100*df1['Z']
df1.plot(kind='line', subplots=True, secondary_y=['Z'])

with matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages("output.pdf") as pdf:
    for cols in df1.columns:
        ## plot 1
        fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
        df1.plot(y=cols, ax=ax1, color='C1')
        ax1.legend(loc=2)
        ## plot 2
        ax2 = ax1.twinx()
        df1.plot(y='Z', ax=ax2)
        pdf.savefig()
```

Comment: Thanks Juan. That worked beautifully. I have two related questions: How to add titles to each chart (e.g. using Column labels or from a list of titles), and how to format the pdf to have two charts per page in portrait mode.

Comment: You can add options to the plots using the methods available in the axes. For example, if you want add the title you add `ax1.set_title('Title of graph1' )`, if you want put the label to the axis then: `ax1.set_ylabel('units of first axis')`, `ax2.set_ylabel('units of z')`.
If you are going to plot several graphs in a page maybe you need to generate several plots with plt.subplots()